# Export a folder of SQL queries into CSV in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, pipeline

I am a newbie to SSIS and currently struggling with executing SQL task saving the result in a result set and exporting each table to a respective CSV using a data flow task.

There are 15 `.sql` files stored in a folder which I am creating a variable called `FolderPath` pointing towards them. Then I create a for each container that reads from a folder and create a variable in the variable mapping which is called `SQLfile`.

Inside the `for-each` container I have an execute SQL task which I changed its file connection variable and edited the expression to `FolderPath + SQLfile`.

Executing this loop works, when the result set value is set to none. Now I am trying to connect the tables created from this loop in a data flow task. I have no idea how to do this but I am guessing it has something to do with the result set. When I change the result set to full result set my loop breaks. I am assuming you cant have a result set inside a loop.

Now I am completely lost as I don't know how to save the result of those 15 tables and how to declare them as source in the data flow task.

Comment: when 'ResultSet' is set to 'Full Result'. In the 'Result Set' tab, you have to assign an object variable to it

Answer (score 0):

Store the query in a variable. Then use the **OLE DB Source** component in the Data Flow Task and set the 'data access mode' to **sql command from variable**.